# Router blocking outside connection

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless, remote, putty

I'm having trouble with connecting into my raspberry from outside. Problem is the internet i'm using is provided from the appartment which i'm living in. And that appartment has a router that blocks from outside connection because of some security reasons(they said).

TL;DR
How do i connect to the raspberry pi if router blocking outside connection?

Comment: There is nothing pi-specific about this question. You'd do it the same way you would do it for any other platform. 

Also, "blocks from outside" could mean a zillion different things. You need to provide more information on how the network is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to a computer outside of your local network you could use SSH to create a reverse tunnel. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46271/140639 for more details.

Comment: Little more detail please and you'll have a great answer!